# What is the common term for the target question of a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, duplicate-questions

Say we have question A that gets closed as a duplicate of question B. We call question A the *duplicate*. However, what name do we have for question B?

*Original question* could do it, but the word *original* sounds more in an historical point of view to me.

I could not find such concept in [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353/209901).

Comment: I usually call them "ohgoshnotthatoldcrapagain". Not sure if that's an official term.

Comment: Why does it have to have a name? What's the actual problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: @EnergyNumbers I have a debate in which I talk about questions and duplicate questions of it. The later I call _duplicates_ and I cannot find the term for the former and I don't like going around with "the question to which it was marked as a duplicate to"-ish sentences.

Comment: Consider 'duplicate target'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> duplicate target

or

> dupe target

It really is as easy as that :)